# having double quote when display value in edittext android

Tags: android, web-services, android-edittext

I'm getting String value from Webservice & try to display String value in Edittext using Android. I manage to display the value but i getting double quote, Example : "12.12".Below is the code i done.Can anyone guide where is my mistake.Thanks in advance.

```
//Get the response
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();
//Convert the stream to readable format
result= convertStreamToString(stream);
    cText.setText(result);
```

---

```
public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) 
 {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because you are getting the output from your webservice with double quotes. If the only problem you are facing is that the `result` string contains double quotes, then you can simply remove the double quotes by using the following code:

```
    String result = convertStreamToString(stream);
    result = result.replace("\"","\\\"");
    System.out.println(result);    //Result string without double quotes
```

Hope this helps.. Thanks..

Comment: I have solved the problem ready..result = result.replace("\"", ""). this is working for me.anyway thanks for your guiding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are sending from your webservice with quotes. To get rid of quotes you can escape them by \" . The content of your InputStreamReader will always be what you read from webservice. This do not add any "" to your String. So must be a webservice problem.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin you may use an extension function

```kotlin
fun String.removeQuotationMarks(): String {
    if (startsWith("\"") && endsWith("\"")) {
        return drop(1).dropLast(1)
    }
    return this
}
```